# VBA Code Error 2450 After changing to ACCDE

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a function that has been in use for a number of months that checks to see if the form that is going to be opened will actually have records to be viewed before opening it.  Recently I decided to change from ACCDB to ACCDE for security purposes.  After making the change over the function started throwing error 2450 "Microsoft Access cannot find the referenced form..."  I can't seem to find anything of use online that could tell me what the cause of this error is and why it only happens with ACCDE.

On a side note I realize the inefficiency of the logic in this function, it's on my list.

```
Public Function ValidateFormToOpen(strFormName As String, strFilter As String, strFieldName As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

Dim intNumberOfRecords As Integer

'If the form is currently open count how many results will be shown
If CheckFormState(strFormName) Then
    intNumberOfRecords = DCount(strFieldName, Access.Forms(strFormName).RecordSource, strFilter)

'If it is closed open it in a hidden state and then count how many records would be shown
Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName, acDesign, "", strFilter, , acHidden
    intNumberOfRecords = DCount(strFieldName, Access.Forms(strFormName).RecordSource, strFilter)
    DoCmd.Close acForm, strFormName
End If

'If there were records that will be shown return true
If intNumberOfRecords > 0 Then
    ValidateFormToOpen = True
Else
    ValidateFormToOpen = False
End If


Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, strMODULE_NAME & ".ValidateFormToOpen on " & strFormName)
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

This is the CheckFormState Code

```
Public Function CheckFormState(sFormName As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    If Access.Forms(sFormName).Visible = True Then
        CheckFormState = True
    End If


    Exit_Handler:
        Exit Function

    Err_Handler:
        CheckFormState = False
        Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

Comment: Have you identified which line triggers the error?  Could the error be happening in `CheckFormState(strFormName)`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really tell, once it hits ACCDE I can't debug or anything to figure out what is going on. Though I threw up the code in case you wanted to see it.

Comment: With no way to identify which line triggers the error, you're really up the creek without a paddle.  Do not accept that.  One measure you can adopt is to add line numbers to your VBA procedures.  Then you can use `Erl` in your error handling (see the help topic for details).  You can use MZ-Tools to manage line numbering.  You wouldn't even need to number everything; you could number only those procedures which are involved with the problem.

Comment: An interesting idea, it wouldn't be hard to add even a crude numbering system such as a intCurrentLine variable that gets incremented as code executes and is then included in the error that gets logged.

Comment: It is this line `DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName, acDesign, "", strFilter, , acHidden`.  This line works no problem while in ACCDB format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ACCDE format database restricts design capabilities in general.  I think that may be why you get an error with this line:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName, acDesign, "", strFilter, , acHidden
```

However I'm not positive that is the complete explanation because when I attempt to open a form in Design View (`DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", acDesign`) in my ACCDE database, Access gives me a different error message:

*"The command you specified is not available in an .mde, .accde, or .ade database."*

So I don't know what the solution is for your goal, but I believe it can not be based on opening a form in Design View.

Comment: To be honest it makes complete sense that this functionality would be blocked out since design view isn't really something that would be used with a deployment version.  I will have to explore other ways to complete this.  I would have much preferred your error message to mine though haha.

Comment: Yes it makes sense, and I should have spotted that detail sooner!  Oops.  I was trying to figure out why Access couldn't find the darn form.  :-)

Comment: Yes, that error threw me completely in the wrong direction.  In the end I also realized that ACCDE doesn't even hide the tables which was one of the main things I was hoping for, so I am not really heart broken that ACCDE won't work great for me.

Comment: You could set the db properties so that it starts with the Navigation Pane closed and disable special keys so the users can't open the Navigation Pane.

Comment: Yes, I have been looking into that as well.  But I haven't been able to plan a 100% secure AND safe way of accomplishing the level of security that I want.  I know it will have to be a combination of encrypting the backend, saving as ACCDE, disabling bypass, disabling special keys. But I am not sure if Page level locking is a valid option with the current database requirements.  Then this ACCDE issue is going to be another obstacle that I overcome.  But I suppose all that is probably another post on its own.